# Array address in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some code like this :

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int array[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> array[i];  
}

int tmp[n - 1];
tmp[0] = 1;
```

With input : `1 10`  I found that the value of `array[0]` was changed , instead of `10` it has the same with `tmp[0]`.

Then I realized with that input the length of `tmp[]` became zero. So I print the address of `array[]` and `tmp[]` with:

```
printf("%d\n %d\n", array, tmp);
```

and found they had the same address.

I want to figure out what will happen if an array has a length of 0; so I tried this:

```
int array[1];
array[0] = 10;

int tmp[0];
tmp[0] = 1;
```

address:

```
array[]: 1363909056
tmp[]  : 1363909052
```

It looks just like the previous code (except the input part). But `tmp[0]` and `array[0]` has different values and address now.

And I'm really confused that `tmp` has smaller address then `array`.

So my question is:

1. What will happen if I declare an array of length zero?
2. Why these two codes works different? (they look the same to me :) )

Comment: `int array[n];` isn't standard c++.

Comment: I have tried a lot with different 'declarations' but it just make more confused

Comment: `tmp[0] = 1;` is simply invoking undefined behavior. Not really worthy thinking about a result accessed from `tmp[0]` thereafter.

Comment: `int tmp[0];` is illegal anyways. Asking about the exact behavior of invalid code is not very useful. If you are asking about a C++ dialect like gnu++, please make that explicit.

Comment: Never thought about the ' undefined behavior ' thing before. I looked up it in wikipedia and got clear now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "undefined behavior". After declaring, in your case

```
int tmp[0];
```

The next thing that happens is:

```
tmp[0]=1;
```

Since `tmp[0]` does not exist, this is undefined behavior. Your problem is not that the array was declared with size 0 (that's not exactly kosher on its own merits, but is not the issue here), but the undefined behavior as a result of overwriting memory past the end of the array.